# Need help figuring out a LINQ query w/ EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a bunch of entities I'd like to list in a wiki-like manner, where they would be organized by the first letter of their title, followed by a count of how many entities exist per letter.  So, something like:

A (5)
B (7)
C (4)
etc.

I'm not sure how to go about it, though.  A rough pseudocode version:

```
from g in Games select g.title, /* count */
    where /* g.title.firstLetter */ ASC
```

The commented out parts are where I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from game in games
group game by game.Title.Substring(0,1) into g
select new {
    Key = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count()
};
```

Free handed that, so there may be compiler errors, but I believe that should be the linq query to get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Games
       .GroupBy(g => g.title.FirstOrDefault())
       .Select(g => new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from g in Games
            group g by g.title[0] into cg
            select new { FirstLetter = cg.Key, Count = cg.Count() };
```